# Convergence of a double integral - Couldn't understand the intuition behind it

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have worked with convergence of simple integrals, but never seen a double integral.

How would you explain whether this converges or not? What methods can I use?

$$\iint_D\frac{{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y}{x^2+y^2+1}$$

Comment: Related: [Convergence tests for improper multiple integrals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15261/convergence-tests-for-improper-multiple-integrals)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** With $D=\mathbb{R}^2$, use polar coordinates to show convergence on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, use that the integrand is always positive to conclude convergence on any domain $D$.